# How to identify the activation function at a specific layer of a loaded keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After loading a trained model in keras, `model.summary()` gives the description of the network layers. But it doesn't contain the information about the activation function in the layers.

How to identify which activation function is used in a specific layer?

Answer (score 6):

You need to access .activation attribute of each layer (if it has one). Try this code sample:

```
for i, layer in enumerate (model.layers):
    print (i, layer)
    try:
        print ("    ",layer.activation)
    except AttributeError:
        print('   no activation attribute')
```

Output example:

```
0 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x000001E72A499C88>
     <function relu at 0x000001E727D9E558>
1 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x000001E72A49C388>
   no activation attribute
2 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x000001E72A49AB48>
     <function relu at 0x000001E727D9E558>
3 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x000001E72A49A3C8>
   no activation attribute
4 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x000001E72A48CD88>
   no activation attribute
5 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dropout object at 0x000001E72A484D88>
   no activation attribute
6 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000001E72A484A48>
     <function softmax at 0x000001E727D95E58>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could substitute the `try-except` statement with `hasattr`.

For example, given a simple `VGG16`

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

vgg = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(
    include_top=True,
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=(224,224,3),
    classes=1000,
    classifier_activation='softmax'
)
```

you can print the activation of each layer (together with its name) in this way:

```
for i,layer in enumerate(vgg.layers):
    if hasattr(layer, "activation"):
        print(layer.name, layer.activation)
    else:
        print(layer.name, 'None')
```

Which results in:

```
input_1 None
block1_conv1 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block1_conv2 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block1_pool None
block2_conv1 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block2_conv2 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block2_pool None
block3_conv1 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block3_conv2 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block3_conv3 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block3_pool None
block4_conv1 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block4_conv2 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block4_conv3 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block4_pool None
block5_conv1 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block5_conv2 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block5_conv3 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
block5_pool None
flatten None
fc1 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
fc2 <function relu at 0x7f686ba4f290>
predictions <function softmax at 0x7f686ba4a830>
```